# How to determine if a specific event log exists WITHOUT using .NET Framework in VC++?

Tags: c++, winapi, event-log

I wonder if there is any WinAPI that can replace the following function `EventLog::Exists()` and `EventLog::CreateEventSource()` so my code won't rely on the `.NET Framework`.
I will be very grateful if you can give me some advice!

```
#define PRINT_SOURCE_NAME "Microsoft-Windows-PrintService"  
#define PRINT_LOG_NAME "Microsoft-Windows-PrintService/Operational" 
BOOL bRet = EventLog::Exists(PRINT_LOG_NAME );
if (!bRet)
{
    EventLog::CreateEventSource(PRINT_SOURCE_NAME , PRINT_LOG_NAME );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The `EventLog::CreateEventSource` method is just a thin wrapper over editing the registry entries that control the event log.  You can just access these entries directly without .Net by manipulating the registry.

The main entry is `SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\EventLog` and the sub keys represent the available logs.  This MSDN entry has a detailed description of the various values and what they represent

- [Event Log](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363648%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)